# Живой поиск по таблице

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть таблица с валютами, вот пример 1-ой:

```
 <div class="trading__market-table">
  <div class="trading__market-table_vkl">
    <div class="trading__market-table-row" id="moneta1" name="moneta1" onclick='ChangeCoinProdBuySell("moneta1");'>
      <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
        <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green" name="Point_moneta1" onclick='ChangeColorGreenPoint("Point_moneta1");'></div>
        <!-- green -->
        <div class="trading__market-table-coin">moneta1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="trading__market-table-price">0.068<span>67804</span></div>
      <div class="trading__market-table-volume">4644.65</div>
      <div class="trading__market-table-change">+2.5%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Также есть поле для поиска:

```
<div class="tradigng__market-search">
  <div class="trading__h">Markets</div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Как реализовать поиск в таблице по названию монеты `по классу trading__market-table-coin`? Т.е, если я ввожу `moneta1`, он должен оставить мне в таблице только эту монету. Знаю как сделать поиск в обычных таблица, но вот конкретно для моей решение пока не нашел

Comment: я бы организовывал поиск не по таблице, а по данным, из которых состоит эта таблица.

Comment: @Дмытрык Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Каким образом у Вас формируется таблица? Из данных или Вы руками ее заполняете?

Comment: @Дмытрык заполняю руками

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#searchInput");
let arrData = document.getElementsByClassName('trading__market-table-row');
input.addEventListener('blur', showChoice);

function showChoice(event){
let value = event.target.value;
if (value === ""){
 for (let i=0; i<arrData.length; i++){
  let item = arrData[i]
  item.style.display = ""
 }
 return
}
for (let i=0; i<arrData.length; i++){
 let item = arrData[i]
 if (item.id !== value) {
  item.style.display = "none"
 } else {
  item.style.display = ""
 }
}
}
```

```html
  <div class="tradigng__market-search">
  <div class="trading__h">Markets</div>
  <input id="searchInput" type="text">
</div>
 <div class="trading__market-table">
  <div class="trading__market-table_vkl">
<div class="trading__market-table-row" id="moneta1" name="moneta1" >
  <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
    <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green" name="Point_moneta1" '></div>
    <!-- green -->
    <div class="trading__market-table-coin">moneta1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__market-table-price">0.068<span>67804</span></div>
  <div class="trading__market-table-volume">4644.65</div>
  <div class="trading__market-table-change">+2.5%</div>
</div>
<br>
    <div class="trading__market-table-row" id="moneta2" name="moneta2" >
  <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
    <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green" name="Point_moneta2" ></div>
    <!-- green -->
    <div class="trading__market-table-coin">moneta2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__market-table-price">0.068<span>67804</span></div>
  <div class="trading__market-table-volume">4644.65</div>
  <div class="trading__market-table-change">+2.5%</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вроде на стаке пример работает, а как вставляю к себе на страницу, то перестает

Comment: ну, я же скрипт писал на основании того, что Вы предоставили на SO, а не на основании Вашего сайта

Comment: задайте инпуту `id="searchInput"`. Возможно заработает

Comment: я если не задавать классу trading__market-table-row id и name, скрипт будет работать?

Comment: name можно не задавать

Comment: а можно как-то и без смены id? просто куча скриптов висит

Comment: у Вас нет id у целевого инпута

Comment: я про id на trading__market-table-row

Comment: я за смену  id на trading__market-table-row ничего не говорил

Comment: скрипт по какой-то причине не оставляет ничего в таблице при вводе в поиск