# isotope сортировка по определенному имени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html) список:

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    date: function ( itemElem  ) {
              return Date.parse($( itemElem ).find('.date').data('time'));
          },
          popular: function ( itemElem  ) {
              return parseInt($( itemElem ).find('.comment').data('comment'), 10);
          },
          name1: function ( itemElem  ) {
              return $( itemElem ).find('.name1');
          },
          name2: function ( itemElem  ) {
              return $( itemElem ).find('.name2');
          },
          name3: function ( itemElem  ) {
              return $( itemElem ).find('.name3');
          },
  },
  sortAscending: false,
  // sortBy: 'new',
});

// bind sort button click
$('.sort-by-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
  $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.element-item {
  border:1px solid #eee;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  color:#777;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.comment {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button.is-checked {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
<div class="button-group sort-by-button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-value="original-order">ALL</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="date">New</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="popular">Popular</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="name1">Name 1</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="name2">Name 2</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="name3">Name 3</button>
</div>  


<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 1">
    <h3 class="name name1">Name 1</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="02-07-2017">02.07.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="1">1 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 2">
    <h3 class="name name2">Name 2</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="01-01-2018T08:23:11">01.01.2018 08:23:11</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="20">20 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 3">
    <h3 class="name name3">Name 3</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="05-07-2017">05.07.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="33">33 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 1">
    <h3 class="name name1">Name 1</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="20-03-2018T08:23:11">20.03.2018 08:23:11</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="100">100 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 2">
    <h3 class="name name2">Name 2</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="14-10-2017">14.10.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="5">5 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 3">
    <h3 class="name name3">Name 3</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="07-06-2018">07.06.2018</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="1">1 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 1">
    <h3 class="name name1">Name 1</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="01-09-2017">01.09.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="1">1 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 2">
    <h3 class="name name2">Name 2</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="11-11-2017">11.11.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="3">3 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 3">
    <h3 class="name name3">Name 3</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="03-04-2018">03.04.2018</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="26">26 comments</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** Как отсортировать список по определенному имени, т.е. например сначала только все `Name 1`, а потом все остальные?

**Вопрос:** Как отсортировать по дате (формат `DD-MM-YYTHH:MM:SS`, пример `01-01-2018T08:23:11`)?

Не отфильтровать, а именно **отсортировать** и именно **isotope**!

**P.S:** Сейчас из всех пунктов срабатывает только сортировка популярных постов. Сортировка остальных как-то странно срабатывает (не так как положено).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886966/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5/886995#886995

Comment: @Дмытрык, спасибо, но не нахожу связи

Comment: ... ну да, там фильтрация...

Comment: @Дмытрык, с фильтрацией все намного проще было бы

Comment: Так вроде у тебя сортировка работает в примере?

Comment: @Grundy, работает, но не правильно. По дате не учитывает часы, т.е. сортирует первые 2018 года, потом 2017, а потом уже все остальное, т.е. 2018 с часми\минутами. По имени вообще не сортирует как положено

Comment: @Grundy, help me! (~~>.<~~)

Comment: c Name не совсем понял какой результат должен быть, и какие могут быть исходные данные

Comment: С именем, у каждого пункта есть тег (кошка, собака, ...). По клику на кнопку с "кошка" в списке первыми идут пункты с тегом "кошка", а следом все остальные, так же и если кликнуть на собака и т.д. В моем примере тут по аналогии Name 1 (кошка), Name 2 (собака) .... Остальные не сортируются, а просто так и идут по порядку

Comment: @HamSter, то есть просто по наличию тега? а если будет несколько кошек, они внутри должны как-то сортироваться?

Comment: Получается да, по наличию одного тега "кошка" (name 1), пока вроде не предполагается что будут кошка 1, кошка 2 ... только кошка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84903/discussion-between-grundy-and-hamster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с датами заключается в неверном формате строки, которая передается в метод [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Если привести ее к ISO формату: `yyyy-mm-dd`, то сортировка по дате начнет работать корректно.

Сейчас же идет попытка распознать дату: `20.03.2018` по формату `mm.dd.yyyy` из-за этого получается 20 месяц, что некорректно, и, как следствие, результат вызова `parse` - `NaN`.

---

Для сортировки по имени - нужно определить как сравнивать элементы.

Так как имя задается элементом с конкретным классом, самое простое - просто проверить наличие этого элемента, например вернув `.length` - в нужных элементах он будет `1`, и они будут вверху, так как в остальных он будет `0` из-за отсутствия элемента с нужным классом.

Либо воспользоваться методом [`has`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    date: function(itemElem) {
      return Date.parse($(itemElem).find('.date').data('time'));
    },
    popular: function(itemElem) {
      return parseInt($(itemElem).find('.comment').data('comment'), 10);
    },
    name1: function(itemElem) {
      return $(itemElem).find('.name1').length;
    },
    name2: function(itemElem) {
      return $(itemElem).find('.name2').length;
    },
    name3: function(itemElem) {
      return $(itemElem).find('.name3').length;
    },
  },
  sortAscending: false,
  // sortBy: 'new',
});

// bind sort button click
$('.sort-by-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
  $grid.isotope({
    sortBy: sortValue
  });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
.element-item {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.comment {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button.is-checked {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>



<div class="button-group sort-by-button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-value="original-order">ALL</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="date">New</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="popular">Popular</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="name1">Name 1</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="name2">Name 2</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="name3">Name 3</button>
</div>


<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 1">
    <h3 class="name name1">Name 1</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2017-07-02">02.07.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="1">1 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 2">
    <h3 class="name name2">Name 2</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2018-01-01T08:23:11">01.01.2018 08:23:11</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="20">20 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 3">
    <h3 class="name name3">Name 3</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2017-07-05">05.07.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="33">33 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 1">
    <h3 class="name name1">Name 1</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2018-03-20T08:23:11">20.03.2018 08:23:11</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="100">100 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 2">
    <h3 class="name name2">Name 2</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2017-10-14">14.10.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="5">5 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 3">
    <h3 class="name name3">Name 3</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2018-06-07">07.06.2018</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="1">1 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 1">
    <h3 class="name name1">Name 1</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2017-09-01">01.09.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="1">1 comment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 2">
    <h3 class="name name2">Name 2</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2017-11-11">11.11.2017</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="3">3 comments</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item " data-category="it 3">
    <h3 class="name name3">Name 3</h3>
    <span class="date" data-time="2018-04-03">03.04.2018</span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment="26">26 comments</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: СУПЕР!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :* Еще бы по имени решить сортировку, чтобы сначала с опр. именем шли пункты, а потом все остальные)))

Comment: @HamSter, определенное имя это какое? остальные не должны никак сортироваться?

Comment: мой герой!))) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector('.sort-by-button-group');
const grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0];
const children = grid.children;
const originalOrder = []
buttons.addEventListener('click', sorting);

for (let i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
 originalOrder[i] = children[i]
}

function sorting(event) {
const target = event.target
const value = target.dataset.sortValue;
const sortList = []
for (let i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
 sortList[i] = children[i]
}
sortList.sort((a,b) => {
 if (value != "original-order" && value != "category") {
  return (a.classList.contains(value)) ? -1 : 1
 }
 if (value === "category") {
  return a.dataset.category < b.dataset.category
 }
})
grid.innerHTML = "";
sortList.forEach((item) => {
 grid.appendChild(item)
})
if (value === "original-order") {
  originalOrder.forEach((item) => {
  grid.appendChild(item)
 })
}
}
```

```css
.element-item {
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="button-group sort-by-button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-sort-value="original-order">original order</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="mercury">Mercury</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="tellurium">Tellurium</button>
  <button class="button" data-sort-value="category">category</button>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal mercury" data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid tellurium" data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal mercury" data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid tellurium" data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто! Еще бы с isotope все это связать, потому как на нем много чего еще завязано.

Comment: к сожалению, в Jquery не силен